# Nginx RDP gateway tunnel

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, terminal-services

I've configured nginx to proxy https traffic to a RDS connection broker. The https connection works and i can see the webpage of the RDS server and login to it. When i want to launch a remote app this doesn't work.

This is my reverse-proxy.conf

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name work.domain.com
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/work.domain.com/work.domain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/work.domain.com/work.domain.com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://10.11.75.2;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```